# Get Selenium WebDriver locale

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, locale

How can I get current browser locale from WebDriver?
There is the way to set locale, e.g.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();  
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en");
m_webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But the problem is that it doesn't always work for some reason (not sure, but seems it doesn't work for Windows 8).
So I need to run driver with the set preferences, get browser locale to make sure it works or not, and use appropriate locale for UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the following JavaScript in WebDriver to get it correct:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```